# Jquery Math, Select Dropdown Value + Text Field

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu, file-io

I am trying to multiply the contents of a text box called qty1 by the price in a select box that is retrieved using ajax.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#stock1').on('change', function (){

        var newValue1 = $.getJSON('select2.php', {stockID: $(this).val()}, function(data){
                    var options = '';
                   for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) { 
    options += data[x]['priceeach']; 
    }
     $('#priceeach1').text(options);

    var qty1 = $("#qty1").text();
    var priceeach1 =  $("#priceeach1").text();

     $('#linetotal1').text(priceeach1 * qty1);

                });
            });
        });
        </script>
    <script>
```

The script changes the values in this html :

```
Price Each : &pound;<span id="priceeach1"></span> - Line Total : &pound;<span id="linetotal1"></span>
```

The priceeach1 values are changed, but the linetotal1 value stay at 0, even when the select box is changed or the values in qty1 are changed. What should happen is priceeach1 from the drop down is multiplied by the text box qty1. For example if the priceeach1 = 20.00 and the qty1 was 2 linetotal1 would be 40.00 , but all I get at present is 0 .

Comment: also qty1 must be parsed

Comment: please alert the  priceeach1 and qty1 and tell as what do you get

Comment: qty1 comes up blank but priceeach1 comes up correct

Comment: is priceeach1 and qty1 a text box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `qty1` as you say in the description is a textbox. And you are getting its value using the `text()` property. That's why you get blank as an answer.

Use the `.val()` [property](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to get the value of a textbox.

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse the values as `Float` or `Int` using `parseFloat or parseInt`

```
var qty1 = $("#qty1").html();
var priceeach1 =  $("#priceeach1").html();
 var total=parseFloat(priceeach1)  * parseInt(qty1);
 $('#linetotal1').html(total);
```

Comment: qty will be a whole number e.g 1 , where as priceeach1 will be a decimal number e.g 20.00 , so im not sure if this makes any difference.

Comment: if I alert total it comes up with NaN